# Webpack localIdentName mismatch on server and client in a React SSR application

Tags: css, webpack, css-modules

I am trying to use Css modules with React SSR and i have added the following webpack config .

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
            },{
                test:/\.(s*)css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: {
                                mode: 'local',
                                localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
                            },
                            import: true,
                            importLoaders: true,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                    }
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
```

this generates the following css files in the dist bundle

```
.Home\.module__Container___3B08 {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red; }
```

Where as in my DOM the div has the following style

```
<div class="Home-module__Container___14QBF">
```

how do i make this correct ? and why is the webpack config different with the one in the browser

Comment: Read through - https://javascriptplayground.com/css-modules-webpack-react/ and check if your setup is correct. Also how are you populating the css file name in your DOM?

Comment: @MonikaMangal i had looked at the link already that you have shared and the problem is the link is outdated using deprecated `ExtractTextPlugin ` and i have configured it correctly also as it is generating the hash not not properly as per the browser

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the CSS Modules configuration in .babelrc file under plugins. Then only the CSS generated will match with the one in your html.

.babelrc

```
"plugins": [
   ["react-css-modules", {
     "generateScopedName": "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
    }]
 ],
```

Update :

Had to use `css-modules-require-hook` for server side CSS rendering and `generic-names` for generating hash in both client and server.

index.js

```
const hook = require( "css-modules-require-hook" );
const genericNames = require( "generic-names" );

const generate = genericNames( "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]", {
   context: process.cwd(),
});

// Scope Generator function.
hook( {
    generateScopedName: ( c, path ) => {
        return generate( c, path );
    },
} );
```

webpack.config.js

```
const genericNames = require( "generic-names" );
const generate = genericNames( "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]", {
  context: process.cwd(),
});

const getLocalIdent = ( loaderContext, localIdentName, localName ) =>
    generate( localName, loaderContext.resourcePath );

.....
{
    loader: "css-loader",
    options: {
        modules: {
           getLocalIdent,
        },
     },
 },
```

For more, check this repo: https://github.com/ajayvarghese/react-ssr/tree/css-modules.
Note: Repo uses updated versions of babel packages.

Comment: I tried this but it's not working, i also added the library react css modules which is deprecated and also added the new babel one without any luck

Comment: There's some mismatch in hash generation in serverside and clientside. If you avoid hash:base64:5 part, it might work. Not a proper solution, though. Otherwise you can generate scopeName by using a custom function.

Comment: `There's some mismatch in hash generation in serverside and clientside. this is what i want to know why ?

Comment: Probably css-loader (client) and css-modules-transform (server), are following different methods to generate the hash. There is an issue raised in css-loader git  saying same. It's due to the dependencies which they are following.
Here's the issue https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/877

Comment: That's why I proposed using a custom scope generator, or use without hash.
like `[name]__[local]`

Comment: Issue is still open in css-modules-require-hook ( used by css-modules-transform) https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules-require-hook/issues/119

Comment: @RahulSingh I tried using a custom scope generator function. It's working for me.

Comment: can you add the custom scope logic here @Ajay

Comment: @RahulSingh Did you try the solution?